# JavaScript to check textfield against array?

Tags: javascript

hello all im trying to make a postcode checker JavaScript function that checks the textfield against an array of postcodes and if the text contains a postcode in the array it says we cant deliver to you and if it doesnt show up in the list then it says we can deliver to you, here is the code i have so far.

```
   <script>

        var postcodes = "AB1, AB2, AB23, AB3, AB30, AB31, AB32, AB33, AB34, AB35, AB36, AB41, AB42, AB43, AB44, AB45, AB51, AB52, AB53, AB54, AB55, DD10, DD9, DD10, DD11, DD2, DD3, DD4, DD5, DD7, DD8, DD9, PH11, PH12, FK17, G82, G83, G84, PA20, PA21, PA22, PA23, PA24, PA25, PA26, PA27, PA28, PA29, PA30, PA31, PA32, PA33, PA34, PA35, PA36, PA37, PA38, PA41, PA42, PA43, PA44, PA45, PA46, PA47, PA48, PA49, PA60, PA61, PA62, PA63, PA64, PA65, PA66, PA67, PA68, PA70, PA71, PA72, PA73, PA74, PA75, PA76, PA77, PA78, DG7, KA1, KA10, KA11, KA12, KA13, KA14, KA15, KA16, KA17, KA18, KA19, KA2, KA20, KA21, KA22, KA23, KA24, KA25, KA26, KA27, KA28, KA29, KA3, KA30, KA4, KA5, KA6, KA7, KA8, KA9, PA17, FK10, FK11, FK12, FK13, FK14, DG1, DG10, DG11, DG12, DG13, DG14, DG16, DG2, DG3, DG4, DG5, DG6, DG7, DG8, DG9, KA6, ML12, G60, G61, G62, G64, G65, G66, G81, G82, G83, DD1, DD2, DD3, DD5, EH21, EH22, EH31, EH32, EH33, EH34, EH35, EH36, EH39, EH40, EH41, EH42, TD13, EH1, EH10, EH12, EH13, EH14, EH15, EH16, EH17, EH2, EH20, EH21, EH28, EH29, EH3, EH30, EH4, EH5, EH6, EH7, EH8, EH9, FK1, FK10, FK11, FK12, FK13, FK14, FK15, FK16, FK17, FK18, FK19, FK2, FK20, FK21, FK3, FK4, FK5, FK6, FK7, FK8, FK9, DD6, FK10, KY1, KY10, KY11, KY12, KY13, KY14, KY15, KY16, KY2, KY3, KY4, KY5, KY6, KY7, KY8, KY9, G1, G11, G12, G14, G15, G2, G20, G21, G32, G41, G43, G45, G51, G53, G76, AB37, IV1, IV10, IV11, IV12, IV13, IV14, IV15, IV16, IV17, IV18, IV19, IV2, IV20, IV21, IV22, IV23, IV24, IV25, IV26, IV27, IV28, IV3, IV4, IV40, IV41, IV42, IV43, IV44, IV45, IV46, IV47, IV48, IV49, IV5, IV51, IV52, IV53, IV54, IV55, IV56, IV6, IV7, IV8, IV9, KW1, KW10, KW11, KW12, KW13, KW14, KW2, KW3, KW5, KW6, KW7, KW8, KW9, PA34, PA38, PA39, PA40, PH19, PH20, PH21, PH22, PH23, PH24, PH25, PH26, PH30, PH31, PH32, PH33, PH34, PH35, PH36, PH37, PH38, PH39, PH40, PH41, PH42, PH43, PH44, PA10, PA11, PA13, PA14, PA16, PA18, PA19, EH46, EH55, G33, G65, G66, G67, G68, G69, G71, G72, G73, G74, G75, ML1, ML10, ML11, ML12, ML2, ML3, ML4, ML5, ML6, ML7, ML8, ML9, EH10, EH18, EH19, EH20, EH22, EH23, EH24, EH25, EH26, EH37, EH46, AB37, AB38, AB56, IV30, IV31, IV32, IV36, PH26, KW1, KW15, KW16, KW17, DD2, FK14, FK15, FK19, FK21, KY13, PH1, PH10, PH11, PH12, PH13, PH14, PH15, PH16, PH17, PH18, PH2, PH3, PH4, PH5, PH6, PH7, PH8, PH9, G46, G77, G78, PA1, PA10, PA11, PA12, PA14, PA3, PA4, PA5, PA6, PA7, PA8, PA9, EH26, EH38, EH43, EH44, EH45, EH46, ML12, TD1, TD10, TD11, TD12, TD13, TD14, TD15, TD2, TD3, TD4, TD5, TD6, TD7, TD8, TD9, ZE1, ZE2, ZE3, FK15, FK16, FK17, FK18, FK19, FK20, FK21, FK6, FK7, FK8, FK9, G63, EH27, EH30, EH47, EH48, EH49, EH52, EH53, EH54, EH55, HS1, HS2, HS3, HS4, HS5, HS6, HS7, HS8, HS9"

        function postcodechk() {
            if (document.forms["frm1"]["postcode"].value == postcodes) {
                alert("we dont deliver to you im afraid")
            } else {
                alert("we deliever to you")
            }



        }
    </script>

</head>
    <body>
        <form name="frm1" onsubmit="return postcodechk();" >
        <table>
            <tr><td>Postcode: </td><td><input type="text" name="postcode"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>     

    </body>
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function postcodechk() {
  if (postcodes.indexOf(document.forms["frm1"]["postcode"].value) === -1) {
    alert("we dont deliver to you im afraid")
  } else {
    alert("we deliever to you")
  }
}
```

Comment: It keeps making a new file within the folder the php file is held is that normal ?

Comment: shouldn't it be: if (postcodes.indexOf(document.forms["frm1"]["postcode"].value) == -1) { alert(we dont deliver to you);}

Comment: it works only problem is that it makes a file each time i use the form ? http://postimg.org/image/xislneg17/

Comment: it makes a file? i dont see you are doing that complex code here. Are you doing any other operations while form submitting?

Comment: @MrJoshFisher, 'makes file'? Please explain... however, if you want to stop submitting add return false... So, on submit - if there are no errors - form will be submitted, otherwise, show errors -> stop submit. AND, of course, make php checking too (client side is not enough, js validation can be easily bypassed)

Comment: please see the link to the image in my last comment everytime i click submit it creates a file called map.php?postcode= and whatever postcode i used